# Attachmate Reflections from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, attachmate-reflection

I have been trying to automate Reflections from an Excel macro, code as below. However, there are 2 sessions open, i have attached screenshot of same for reference. Can anyone please help me how i can switch between the already running sessions.   [image]

```
    Public objFM As Object
    Set objFM = GetObject("RIBM")  With objFM
      .WaitForEvent rcEnterPos, "30", "0", 4, 41
      .WaitForDisplayString "code:", "30", 4, 34
      .TransmitTerminalKey rcIBMResetKey
      .TransmitANSI "MTAE"
      .TransmitTerminalKey rcIBMEnterKey
      .WaitForEvent rcKbdEnabled, "30", "0", 1, 1
    End With
```

Comment: `Set pApp = GetObject("Reflection Workspace")  
    Set pFrame = pApp.GetObject("Frame")  
    pFrame.Visible = True  
    Set pView = pFrame.GetViewByTitleText("r5250.rd5x")  
    Set pTerminal = pView.Control  
    Set pScreen = pTerminal.Screen  
    pView.Focus`

Comment: Just in case anyone wants to refer, the above solution works good..